# Exposing a method only to a certain class

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

I've got this question in my head for quite some while now. What if I have a MyObjectManager class that is a manager (obviously) of instances of the class MyObject. So, in the MyObject there are some methods and properties that should only be available to MyObjectManager, and no other class. How do I make this kind of connection? There's no friend class in C#. But even if there's a friend class, a certain case would arise. What if the same MyObject class has other methods and properties that should only be available to other class, MyObjectLogic, and no other (including MyObjectManager)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nested classes will work, but they're not too pretty. As far as I am aware, that's the only way to do it, but it won't work for multiple managers - in that case, you may be out of luck, and might want to implement things in a different way (instead of manager-only methods). You *can* fake it, though, with interface-explicit methods, and have the mangers operate via the interface. But that won't stop others from using the methods if they really wanted to.

Comment: Then maybe you have better options than trying this. Is possible that your object can be splitted into different interrelated objects. What's the reason of allowing to call a method only from the manager? You should provide more information.

Comment: Expose an interface to outer world with only required members while having other members which can be accessed through manager through class instance.

Comment: If you are asking about the usage of class limitations, you can create a generic class with constraints over it. That might help you with what you want.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain why you would want to do this? The reason why you are inheriting from your parent class is for the child classes to share the same methods and properties. I'm thinking that this is more of a design issue than a technical one.

Comment: Actually the two managers situation is just an example and maybe it is better to separate it if it were the case. Regarding the issue, I'm trying to make a simulation and each object's state will be updated each tick by calling its `AdvanceTime(float dt)` method from `MyObjectManager`. Only `MyObjectManager` class should call the `AdvanceTime(float dt)` (since it is the only class that calculates the ticks). Currently, `AdvanceTime(float dt)` is a public method so that `MyObjectManager` can call it. However, that also means all other objects can call it, thus destroying the simulation.